# pipe or directive for tables with search, filter and sorting options in angular 4

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-pipe

I have multiple tables which share a similar functionalities but fetches data from different API. What is the best PIPE or DIRECTIVE?

For example: I have an API to fetch cities

```
baseUrl: /cities
```

For search I need to append

```
baseUrl + 'search=city name'
```

For sorting also I would append additional data

```
baseUrl + 'sort=-name,active'
```

and so on, but I need to make a remote call everytime user applies any filter.

Comment: Uhm, your question is incomplete, I think. maybe you should provide some code? Right know it seems like you can just add event listeners (`ngModelChange`) for example, and make your API calls every time the user changes input

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan Thanks for the quick response, I wanted to make something I can reuse. I was thinking to make directives and when on clicks try changing the query strings

Comment: Why is `(ngModelChange)` not reusable? I mean, if you post your code, this may become more clear for people who do not see what you really are attempting to do.

Comment: I have too many tables and I every table has an option to sort, filter, and so, all i need to do is to change the queryString depending on the user inputs, and call the API.

Comment: You can post a simplified version. But your problem does not seem like anything related to Pipes or Directives

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfrxqu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html